# How can you remove a dynamically created div with unique id?

Tags: jquery

I'm only going to post the code that's relevant. If you need my whole code, let me know.

Anyway, I have the following code:

```
 var deck = [];
 var c = 0;
$('#add').click(function(){
     var addToDeck = $('input[name=searchItem]').val();
     addToDeck = addToDeck.toLowerCase();
     deck.push(addToDeck);
   $('#save').append('<div id="cardList' + (c++) + '">' + database[deck[deck.length-1]].name + '</div>');
 });
```

Which dynamically adds divs with unique id's each time a certain button is pressed (ex: cardList1, cardList2, etc). Now, if the user clicks on some div with a particular id (say cardList2), I want to remove it from the list.

I tried something like this:

```
  $(document).on('click','#save', function(){
   $('#cardList' + 'c').remove();
  });
```

But it doesn't work. I think I'm in the right direction though.

Just to re-iterate, this is a card game deck building application... so I want to make it easier on a user by letting them remove a card that's already in their deck just by clicking on the div with the card id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second code example, `c` is not defined or does not have the value you expect. This should work though:

```
$('#save').on('click','[id^=cardList]', function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

It will listen to click events on all elements having an ID which starts with `cardList` and which are descendants of the element `#save` (instead of listening to clicks on `#save`). It makes simpler because `this` will just refer to the element that was clicked and you want to remove.

You could also give the elements an additional class and use it instead of the attribute-starts-with selector:

```
// for example
$('<div />', {
    id: 'cardList' + (c++), 
    'class': 'myclass', 
    text: database[deck[deck.length-1]].name
}).appendTo('#save');

// somewhere else

$('#save').on('click','.myclass', function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

You should also think about whether you need unique IDs at all.

Answer (score 1):

Create the new div as a jQuery object:

```
$('#save').append('<div>', {'id':'cardList' + (c++)});
```

Then it will be accesible.

Comment: Your usage of `append` is incorrect, I assume you meant `.append($('<div>', {'id':'cardList' + (c++)}));`. It will have the same effect as what the OP currently has, so it won't solve their problem.